# What priority/precedence is applied to multiple xsl:imported stylesheets?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

What priorities or precedence rules, if any, are applied to `A.xsl`, `B.xsl`, and `C.xsl` by virtue of the order in which they are imported?

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:my="http://me"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:import href="A.xsl"/>        
    <xsl:import href="B.xsl"/>
    <xsl:import href="C.xsl"/>

    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#import and "[Definition: The stylesheet levels making up a stylesheet are treated as forming an import tree. In the import tree, each stylesheet level has one child for each xsl:import declaration that it contains.] The ordering of the children is the declaration order of the xsl:import declarations within their stylesheet level.

[Definition: A declaration D in the stylesheet is defined to have lower import precedence than another declaration E if the stylesheet level containing D would be visited before the stylesheet level containing E in a post-order traversal of the import tree (that is, a traversal of the import tree in which a stylesheet level is visited after its children). Two declarations within the same stylesheet level have the same import precedence.]"

So for your sample the import precedence (lowest first) `A`, `B`, `C`, `Main`.